# Объединение Delphi и Unity3D проектов

Tags: unity3d, delphi, exe

Моя программа моделирует некий физический процесс. Большой объем мат части по этому процессу был описан другим человеком в проекте на Delphi. Моделированием этого процесса  я занимаюсь в unity3D. Необходимо доработать мат часть, но мне проще дописать ее в Delphi, чем переписывать весь проект в JS или C# скрипты. 
 Я планирую скомпилировать exe файл Delphi, который в процессе обработки данных сохранит все расчеты в отдельный файл. Когда расчеты завершатся, этот exe файл закроется и должен открыться exe файл Unity3D, который прочитает данные из сохраненного файла и смоделирует их.
Вопрос:
1) Каким образом объединить 2 exe файла, что бы последующий запускался по завершению предыдущего, но что бы физически это был один exe файл.
2) Может кто-то имел подобный опыт и сможет подсказать менее топорный способ подружить мою мат часть Delphi и моделирование в Unity3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Чтобы сделать это - есть топорный вариант, который называется BAT конвертированный в EXE. То есть складываете exe-шники в отдельную папку, в корне создаете BAT, который открывает все по очереди, а потом просто конвертируете его в EXE)

2) Я бы посоветовал вам покопать в сторону взаимодействия в виде сервер-клиент. То есть клиент будет на Unity сервер на Delphi, и Unity таким образом сможет безболезненно принимать данные, которые присылает сервер.

P.S. Пришел сюда случайно из одного топика Habrahabr'а:D

Comment: >Пришел сюда случайно из одного топика Habrahabr'а:D

 про раздел Q&A на Хабре?))

Answer (score 0):

На какой платформе должна запускаться программа на Unity? В юнити используется полноценный .NET, правда устаревшей версии, поэтому можно использовать все возможности платформы (на PC). Можно собрать логику работы (математическую часть) в dll и вызывать ее из Unity3d.